# Exception with pipe (|) in url when accessing client.execute(new HttpGet(url))

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access snaptoroads in Roads API and this requires `pipes (|)` as a separator between coordinates.

Whenever I use the pipe in the url for `client.execute(new HttpGet(url))` it creates an exception in java. I can try an alternative separator and there's no exception, but snaptoroads insists on the `"|"` separator.

I am using Eclipse (4.2.1), Android (4.1.2), and GoogleMap (v2).

Has anyone found a similar issue? I assume this combination is widely used, but I cannot find a solution by searching Google, stack overflow, etc.

Any advice will be gratefully received.

Regards

Comment: Details? Code + the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding the lat, long you are sending,

### Working example:

```
String url = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path="+URLEncoder.encode("-35.27801,149.12958|-35.28032,149.12907","UTF-8")+"&interpolate=true&key=XXXX";
```

Comment: Marvellous. This has solved the problem which has been baffling me for hours.

Comment: @pat2016 I am glad, if it helped you can accept the answer

Comment: I hit Enter too quickly. Thank you for your solution Pulkit.

Comment: You can see accept the answer on the left of my solution

Comment: OK. Accepted. Thank you again.